# Is there any way to put @JsonView on Controller method with QueryResult returnType?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have an `ViewModel` and put `json`annotation on some fields according [this post of spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) like below:

```
public class SurveyViewModel{
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long     id;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String   title;
    private String   description;
    private String   endDate;
    //Here is getters & setters
}
```

When I retrieve data from my `REST Controller`, if return Type of my method is `List`, json-result is OK:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllGrid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@ResponseBody
public List<SurveyViewModel> getAll{
    return ModelMapper.mapList(iSurveyService.getAll(), SurveyViewModel.class);
}
```

But when I apply paging on my result & change return type of this method to `QueryResult`, json-result is empty:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllGrid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@ResponseBody
public QueryResult<SurveyViewModel> search(String order, int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
    return ModelMapper.mapQueryResult(iSurveyService.getAllGrid(new SearchOption("", order, pageNumber, pageSize)), SurveyViewModel.class);
}
```

When I apply paging on my result with above method, `pageNumber, totalRecords & pageSize` added to my json result and original-data add to `entityList` as inner json object, Here is my`QueryResult` in json format **without** apply `@JsonView`:

```
{
"pageNumber" : 0,
"totalRecords" : 1,
"pageSize" : 10,
"entityList" : [{
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "survey1",
        "description" : "...",
        "endDate" : "2017/01/18",
        },{
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "survey2",
        "description" : "...",
        "endDate" : "2016/11/18",
    }]
}
```

Now my question is, Is there any way to put `@JsonView` on Controller method with `QueryResult` returnType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryResult` is an object that I use for pagination, I solve my problem by putting `@jsonView` on properties of `QueryResult` class, like below:

```
public class QueryResult<T> {
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private int pageNumber;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private int totalRecords;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private int pageSize;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)
    private List<T> entityList = new ArrayList<T>();
    //Here is getters & setters
}
```